# can two sublevel sets have different "shapes"?

Tags: convex-optimization, convex-geometry

I wondered if two sublevel sets of a convex function can have different shapes. For example - in the example image below the outer sublevel is a circle while the inner sublevel is ellipse.
Can you provide an example of such a function?
Thanks

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLHAp.png)

Comment: $f(x,y)=x^2+y^4$

Comment: this function doesn't have different shapes:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%2By%5E4+from+-1+to+1